# Input parse argument as a variable in python command line?

Tags: python, parsing, arguments, argparse

I´m trying to input a string variable as a parse argument.

Run the code with following line:

```
for i in range(0,5):
  para=str(i)+"test.params"
  !python test.py --model I3D_resnet50 --resume-params para
```

The parse argument is added in `test.py`:

```
parser.add_argument('--resume-params', type=str, default='default.params',
                        help='path of parameters to load from.')
```

But the code is not working, even if i add `nargs='*'` in `parse.add_argument`.
Is it possible that a variable can be input the parse argument?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: It should be `nargs`, not `ngars`.

Comment: @DeepSpace it want to execute the command line several times with a different `para` string.
@I'L'I thanks, edited

Comment: First, does your `test.py` handle the commandline as expected when executed from a shell?  As for that `!python ...` loop, where is that being done?  Looks like a `ipython/jupyter notebook`?

Comment: @hpaulj im using Google Colab Shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a little script that echos the `sys.argv`:

```
In [173]: cat echo.py
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

In an `ipython` session I can call it with:

```
In [174]: !python3 echo.py test commandline
['echo.py', 'test', 'commandline']
```

Or using a `para` variable:

```
In [175]: para = "test line"
In [176]: !python3 echo.py $para
['echo.py', 'test', 'line']
```

The sys.argv echo could be replaced with a working `argparse` parser.

Comment: thank you very much.
if i use `$para` instead of `para` the loop in the code above works :-)